# Check if a column contains words from another column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

IS there a way we can check if values contained in a column (comma separated) are present in another column(sentence) quickly. Retain the words present and remove the words not present in a pandas dataframe using python ?

Original Data is Like this

```
|sentence      | word|
----------------------

Hello World    |world

Hi how are you |are, car

I am good      |good,bad,sad, am
```

and the result should be like .

```
|sentence      | word|
----------------------

Hello World    |world

Hi how are you |are

I am good      |good, am
```

Performance should be considered as this is a huge dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since most pandas' string operations are not vectorized, you can just do a list comprehension like this:

```
df['word'] = [', '.join([w for w in ws if w in s]) 
                for s, ws in zip(df.sentence.str.lower(), df.word.str.split(',\s*'))
             ]
```

Output:

```
         sentence      word
0     Hello World     world
1  Hi how are you       are
2       I am good  good, am
```

**Note**: This is just an idea that needs improvement such as matching words only (e.g. `regex`)

---

**Update** as noted above, here's such an improvement that only matches whole word:

```
 import re
 df['word'] = [', '.join([w for w in ws 
                     if re.search(f'\\b{w}\\b', s)) ]
                for s, ws in zip(df.sentence.str.lower(), df.word.str.split(',\s*'))
             ]
```

Comment: It works , but the only issue i see is it also keeps the word which is partially present.
E.g if  saturn is present in sentence , and trun is in word , it keeps trun.

         sentence                   word
0     Saturn is planet          turn,is

Comment: Can u please check the update once , it doesn't work. I guess there issue with some brackets.

Comment: @user10136853 updated. Moved a square bracket to the correct position.

Comment: A little change in the square bracket and it worked perfectly fine.
Thank you , much appreciate your response.

df['word'] = [', '.join([w for w in ws 
                     if re.search(f'\\b{w}\\b', s)]) 
                for s, ws in zip(df.sentence.str.lower(), df.word.str.split(',\s*'))
             ]

Comment: can u also look into this question of mine 
[link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61960860/is-there-a-way-we-can-check-if-words-from-two-column-of-a-dataframe-are-within-a