# Python calculate number of words that match between two column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text

I want to calculate how many times a list of words appears in a column. Here is my dataframe:

```
original                           people       result
John is a good friend              John, Mary   1
Mary and Peter are going to marry  Peter, Mary  2
Bond just met the Bond girl        Bond         2
Chris is having dinner             NaN          0
All Marys are here                 Mary         0
```

I tried to use the code suggested here [Check if a column contains words from another column in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61933472/check-if-a-column-contains-words-from-another-column-in-pandas-dataframe):

```
import pandas as pd
import re
df['result'] = [', '.join([p for p in po 
                     if re.search(f'\\b{p}\\b', o)) ]
                for o, po in zip(df.original, df.people.str.split(',\o*'))
             ]
# And after I would try to calculate the number of words in column 'result'
```

but then I receive the following message:

```
error: bad escape \o at position 1
```

Could anyone make a suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [39]: df = pd.DataFrame({'original':["John is a good friend", "Mary and Peter are going to marry", "Bond just met the Bond girl", "Chris is having dinner", "All Marys are here"], "people": ["John, Mary", "Peter, Mary", "Bond", '', "Mary"]})

In [40]: df
Out[40]:
                            original       people
0              John is a good friend   John, Mary
1  Mary and Peter are going to marry  Peter, Mary
2        Bond just met the Bond girl         Bond
3             Chris is having dinner
4                 All Marys are here         Mary

In [41]: df['result'] = df.apply(lambda row: sum((row['original'].count(p.strip()) for p in row['people'].split(',') if p), start=0), axis=1)

In [42]: df
Out[42]:
                            original       people  result
0              John is a good friend   John, Mary       1
1  Mary and Peter are going to marry  Peter, Mary       2
2        Bond just met the Bond girl         Bond       2
3             Chris is having dinner                    0
4                 All Marys are here         Mary       1
```

Comment: I don't think string's `.count` counts the words, it just counts substrings.

Comment: I chose this one as the accepted answer because if, for example, in the first row, I search "John is", the code also works well. Otherwise the other answer also works.

Answer (score 3):

Use `split` on both columns and check if each word in "Original" occurs in "people":

```
df["people"] = df["people"].fillna("")
df["result"] = [sum(w in ws for w in s.split()) for s, ws in zip(df["original"], df["people"].str.split(', '))]

>>> df

                            original       people  result
0              John is a good friend   John, Mary       1
1  Mary and Peter are going to marry  Peter, Mary       2
2        Bond just met the Bond girl         Bond       2
3             Chris is having dinner                    0
4                 All Marys are here         Mary       0
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. If for example, in row 1 I want to search instead "John is, Mary", the result is 0. Can you suggest then how I should change the code?

Comment: The above answer only checks for one word matches since I wanted to avoid matching substrings like counting "turn" in "Saturn".